# What does it mean for a topology to be closed?

Tags: general-topology

I'm a physics student taking a course on topology and geometry and my professor mentioned during the lecture, that a topology $T\subseteq P(X)$, where P is a powerset of X, is closed if $T/X$ is open. Whilst rereading my notes I was confused, since an open set is a set where for each element there exists an $\epsilon$-ball that is also contained within this set and the definition of an $\epsilon$-ball requires the existence of a metric. Therefore there must be some sort of metric defined for the subsets of a topology that I must have missed, since I only recall the definition of a metric between the elements of a topology.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: FWIW, the closest sensible statement I can see is, "A subset $T$ of $X$ is closed if $X \setminus T$ is open."

Comment: The open sets in a topology are an abstraction of the open sets in a metric space. It is not required that you have a metric. You really should take real analysis before taking topology. I suspect that is the reason for your confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome. There are some misconceptions here.

#1: a topology is a collection of subsets, with some requirements. When you refer to ‘elements of the topology’ I am worried you mean elements of the space (call it $X$) rather than elements of the topology (seen as a subset of $P(X)$) i.e. open sets.

#2: topology is a super-general concept. Metric spaces all have their metric topologies, but these are special cases of topology and there are many kinds of topological space that aren’t *metrisable* (there is no metric on that set which induces the same topology). So we define ‘open’ to be: any set contained in the topology, and ‘closed’ to be: any set whose complement is open. It so happens that when you’re doing topology on a metric space, this definition of closed agrees with the definition you’re maybe used to, in terms of convergent sequences.

#3: a topology cannot be open or closed (unless you have given $P(X)$ a topology, which would be unusual, and there would have to be more context). A topology *defines* what it means to be open or closed. I think you misinterpreted your professor, and that they actually said: for $A\subset X$, $A$ is closed iff. $X\setminus A$ is open.

So you can talk about $\varepsilon$-balls for metric spaces. But please remember topology is more general than that.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted my professor as well. Perhaps he wanted to define open and closed sets when there is no metric defined, as you mentioned. I will definitely ask him next lecture. Thank you very much for your help :)